# Rewrite file_get_content function with cURL

Tags: php, curl

So I have this function which I'm trying to make with cURL because of server securities `file_get_contents()` is disabled.

```
$url ='https://example.com' .

        '/b/'.urlencode($this->user_ID).'/o/'.urlencode($this->ID);
        $url=$url.'/h/'.urlencode($hash);
        $number=rand(0, 10)/10 ."";
        $url=$url.$number;

    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    preg_match('/<td valign="bottom" class="sum">(.*?)<\/td\>/', $html , $matches);
    return $matches[0];
```

What I have now is this

```
$url ='https://example.com' .

     '/b/'.urlencode($this->user_ID).'/o/'.urlencode($this->ID);
    $number=rand(0, 10)/10 ."";

    $url=$url.$number;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $matches = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    preg_match('/<td valign="bottom" class="sum">(.*?)<\/td\>/', $html , $matches);
    return $matches[0];
```

Is it something like this or I'm totally on wrong way? And how to change now this line - `$html = file_get_contents($url);` ?

Comment: have you tried it? does it work? Also what happened with the `$url.'/h/'.urlencode($hash);` you don't need it anymore?

Comment: I have forget `$url.'/h/'.urlencode($hash);` it is there.. When I run this with curr try i've got error `file_get_content(): https://wrapper is disabled on this server` on this line `$html = file_get_contents($url);`

Comment: you said you want to use curl, why are you running the `file_get_contents` code?

Comment: I don't understand how to change it as I said in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove the call to `file_get_contents` after the curl, you already have the response from the curl request.

replace this

```
$matches = curl_exec($ch);
```

with this

```
$html = curl_exec($ch);
```

Then do preg_match on the response

```
// $html = file_get_contents($url); this line is not needed
preg_match('/<td valign="bottom" class="sum">(.*?)<\/td\>/', $html , $matches);
return $matches[0];
```

Finally, inspect the contents of `$matches` and `$matches[0]`